# Relation between the trace-ratio and ration-trace

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to understand if there is a relation between the two problems

$\max_{\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{S}\right)=1}\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{S}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{S}\right)^{-1}\right)$

and

$\max_{\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{S}\right)=1}\frac{\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{S}\right)}{\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{S}^{H}\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{S}\right)}$

is one an upper\lower bound for the other?